# Event Sourcing with Scala and Immutable Objects: Is it efficient?

Tags: scala, immutability, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm experimenting with Event Sourcing with Scala (I'm new both in this two fields).

I'd like to keep everything as immutable as possible, including aggregate roots.
As a base, I follow Greg Young's example of ES and CQRS (https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r, implemented in C#) and 'translating' this code into Scala.

Question is about object regeneration from event store:

Since my aggregate roots are immutable, for each event of particular entity, new object is created. So, for example, to regenerate entity which has 100 events, 100 instances of this entity should be created and last instance will be the final state.

**Is it efficient or is to too much overhead?**

(I think max events to regenerate from will be 100, since I will store snapshots).

Here is my code:

**Event trait**

```
trait Event {

}
```

**Base class for aggregates**

```
abstract class AggregateRoot {

  ...
  // HERE ENTITY IS REGENERATED FROM EVENTS AND EACH TIME NEW INSTANCE IS CREATED FOR EACH ENTITY  

  def loadFromHistory(history: Seq[Event]): AggregateRoot = {
    var aggregate = this
    history.foreach(e => aggregate = applyChange(e, false))
    aggregate
  }

  def applyChange(event: Event, isNew: Boolean): AggregateRoot
  ...
}
```

**Product Aggregate**

```
case class Product(id: Long, name: String, status: Int, uncommittedChanges: Seq[Event]) extends AggregateRoot {

  def changeName(name: String): Product = {
    applyChange(ProductNameChangedEvent(id = this.id, name = name))
  }

  def applyChange(event: Event, isNew: Boolean = true): Product = {
    val changedProduct = event match {
      case e: ProductCreatedEvent => applyChange(e)
      case e: ProductNameChangedEvent => applyChange(e)      
      case _ => throw new Exception("No event applier")
    }
    // ALSO HERE I'M COPING ALL THE LOCAL (NEW) CHANGES (THAT ARE NOT STORED IN EVENT STORE YET)
    if (isNew) changedProduct.copy(uncommittedChanges = uncommittedChanges :+ event) else changedProduct
  }

  def applyChange(event: ProductCreatedEvent): Product = {
    this.copy(id = event.id, name = event.name)
  }

  def applyChange(event: ProductNameChangedEvent): Product = {
    this.copy(id = event.id, name = event.name)
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: Any answer here will be too general and broad. As always, benchmark your code, see if it is too much overhead. If it is, locate the hot-paths and try to minimize allocations where possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well... when you talk about efficiency, it will always come-down to the choices of your data-structures and how-what are you optimising ?

In this particular case your `Product` looks like this,

```
case class Product(id: Long, name: String, status: Int, changes: Seq[Event])
```

And as you are accumulating your events in `changes`, your efficiency will be determined by the data structure here. You can not just leave it with a general `Seq`.

Now there is the important question which you should ask - what are your use-cases for this `changes` ?

Well... other than all un-known things... I can see that whenever you receive a new event you want to add it to your `changes`. Which means that if you are receiving vary frequent events than you need to optimise the operation of adding it to your `changes`

So... lets say you were using `changes: List[Event]`,

Now, you will have to use `prepend` which is constant time - C instead of `append` which is O(n).

```
// so this line 
if (isNew) changedProduct.copy(changes = changes :+ event) else changedProduct

// will have to changed to
if (isNew) changedProduct.copy(changes = event +: changes) else changedProduct
```

But now you `changes` list will contain events in the reversed order... so you will have to keep in mind that you apply them in reverse order when rebuilding your state.

To know more about the time-complexity of some operations on various collections, you should take a look at this - http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html

Just, remember that "efficiency" on its on it has no meaning. You should always ask - "efficiency... but in doing what ?"

Comment: Here changes: Seq[Event] - are actually uncommitted changes, but not all changes that are stored in event store of this entity.  Yes, you are right about List, thanks.